# Filter object array with pipe Angular 2

Tags: angularjs, angular, typescript, pipe

I have a

> class:

```
export class Todo {
    public id: number;
    public name: string;
    public isCompleted: boolean;
    public dateCreated: Date;
    public userName: string;
}
```

> A service:

```
getTodos(): Observable < Todo[] > {
    return this.http.get(this.todosUrl)
        .map(this.extractData)
        .catch(this.handleError);
}

private extractData(res: Response) {
    let body = res.json();
    return body || {};
}
```

> In my component:

```
getTodos(){
    this.todoService.getTodos()
      .subscribe(
        todos => this.todos = todos,
        error => this.errorMessage = <any>error
      );
}
```

> And html file:

```
<div class="ui large selection animated divided list">
    <a *ngFor="let todo of (todos | todoFilter:false)" class="item">
        <div class="right floated content">
            <div class="ui vertical animated negative button" tabindex="0">
                <div class="hidden content">Delete</div>
                <div class="visible content">
                    <i class="fa fa-trash" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <i class="minus square outline icon"></i>
        <div class="content">
            <div class="header">{{todo.name}}</div>
            <div class="description">{{todo.dateCreated | date:"MMM-dd-yyyy"}}</div>
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
```

The problem is, when I try to use this pipe to `filter` the completed todos, I keep getting an error that say Cannot read property `filter` of `undefined`.

Did I do something wrong or are there any ways to filter it without using an `pipe`?

> My pipe:

```
transform(allTodos: Todo[], args?: boolean){
    if (allTodos === null) {
      return null;
    }
    return allTodos.filter(todo => todo.isCompleted);
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to replace the `if (allTodos === null)` to just `if (!allTodos)`
I think the problem is that you're getting to the `.filter` even while your `this.todos` is still empty since you're only checking that it isn't null.